# Proof that two sets have the same cardinality

Tags: cardinals

Look in the complex plane at the set $\mathbb{R}\cdot1\cup\mathbb{Z}\cdot i\subset\mathbb{C}$, the union of the real line and all whole multiples of $i$. Prove that this set has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$. I'm having trouble finding a bijection. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Do you have to find a bijection?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f :\left(\mathbb{R} \times \lbrace 0 \rbrace\right) \cup \left(\mathbb{Z} . i \right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ by
$$
f(x,0) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      \frac{1}{2k-1}   & \mbox{if }  x=\frac{1}{k} \text{ for an integer }k\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\\
 \frac{-1}{2k-1}   & \mbox{if }  x=\frac{1}{k} \text{ for an integer }k\in \mathbb{Z}_{<0}\\
       x  & \mbox{otherwise.}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
$$
f(n.i) = \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      0   & \mbox{if }  n=0\\
      \frac{1}{2n}  & \mbox{otherwise.}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Show that $f$ is bijective.